# Basis of polynomial degree most 2

Tags: linear-algebra

How would you argue in one sentence that a set of polynomials with degree of most 2 in a set are closed under scalar multiplication and vector addition?
I think it is possible but only when there is a middle term within the equation.  For example if the vector is $(1,x,x^2)$ would this be closed under vector addition of $(1,x,x^2)$ because then it would be $(2,2x,2x^2)$?
I am confused because I did not think non-linear equations would be closed under vector addition or scalar multiplication.

Comment: They are the kernel of the operator $D^2$ (differentiating twice) and kernels of linear operators are subspaces.

Comment: I think you are confusing the basis for the vector space, which will contain three elements, with the terms in each polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$.  To show the polynomials of degree at most 2 are closed under scalar multiplication and addition of polynomials doesn't depend on the choice of basis.

Comment: If two 2nd degree polynomials are added together, then regardless of whether the $x^1$ coefficient or the $x^0$ coefficient of either or both polynomials $= 0$, I don't see how their sum could result in a polynomial of degree higher than $2$.  Similarly, if $f(x)$ is a 2nd degree polynomial, and $k \neq 0$, then $k \times f(x)$ is also a 2nd degree polynomial.  As I understand it, if $f(x)$ is a polynomial, and [within $f(x)$] $n$ is the highest power such that $x^n$ has a non-zero coefficient, then the degree of $f(x) = n.$

Comment: I suppose that you could argue that if $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ and $g(x) = dx^2 + ex + f$, then $f(x) + g(x) = (a + d)x^2 + (b + e)x + (c + f).$  Also, $kf(x) = (ka)x^2 + (kb)x + (kc).$

Comment: One sentence is not limiting if you go the Stream of Consciousness route.

Comment: @copper.hat James Joyce is *not* a role model. :(

Comment: @XanderHenderson i prefer stream of unconsciousness :-).